# Creating (or discovering) a very simple multiple frame text organizing program

Tags: text-editors

I would like to either program, or discover a program, which is of the following simple form:

1. The user can produce, analogous to websites in html, X number of resizable frames.
2. Each frame serves as a simple text editor, which you can type into and save.
3. The whole configuration (contents and resized window config) can be saved.

The goal is to have a mostly white space which I can organize into text as I please, mostly for organizational purposes, list of goals, schedule, etc. The simpler the better.

Does something close to this exist?

If not, what languages are ideal for such a setup? I know some C and Python and Html, and am willing to learn. It seems to me this should be a relatively easy program to make, but I need a little direction before starting.

EDIT: I should clarify that I am not looking for a text editor, per se. I'm looking for a way to organize information that can be "frozen" and "unfrozen". Mostly it will be for the user to look at, as a way to organize information on a week by week or month by month scale. It's somewhat analogous to a calendar. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I am very positive that you can save window configurations in Emacs. It certainly fails the ‘very simple’ requirement, though.

Comment: Can you have frames in Emacs? I do not mean tabs, I mean resizable frames as in a simple HTML webpage.

Comment: You can have multiple windows in one frame (Emacs terminology), where an Emacs-frame is usually called "Window" everywhere else. Each window (Emacs terminology) can show any buffer you want it to show, where a buffer is usually associated with a specific file. See http://i.imgur.com/ZPNbt.png for an example of one frame, showing five different windows, displaying four different buffers (hence the same text in two windows, if I change it in one, it also changes in the other).

Comment: Thanks. This is not ideal, but it is close to what I'm asking for. I would be happy with a recommendation for what languages or tools to program with. I think I should be able to do this simply and get exactly what I want.